# Handling errors and success in same format

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to create a more robust method that returns two different object types depending on results.

If the result is negative then return CustomError object, but if the result is positive then return Auto object.

Example below to demonstrate.

**AutoService.cs**

```
public class AutoService {
        public async Task<object> Create(NewAuto model)
        {
            var auto = new Auto {
              Type = model.Type,
              Year = model.Year,
              // other parameters
            }
            try {
            await _autoDb.Create(auto);
            }

                catch (Exception e) {
// return this error object if something broken
                return new CustomError { Message = "It is broken" }
                }

//return the Auto entity if successful
                return auto;
            }
    }
```

CustomError.cs

```
public class CustomError {
     public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

In the current format the when calling Create method i will need to cast the result which brings headaches of its own (cast against CustomError or Auto class for e.g.).

Any advice how i can do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a class to represent the result, something like:

```
class EntityResult<T> {
    public EntityResult(T entity) {
        Success = true;
        Entity = entity;
    }

    public EntityResult(string error) {
        Success = false;
        Error = error;
    }

    bool Success {get; }
    T Entity { get; }
    string Error { get; }
}
```

Usage would be like:

```
public async Task<EntityResult<Auto>> Create(NewAuto model) {
    var auto = new Auto {
        Type = model.Type,
        Year = model.Year,
        // other parameters
    };
    try {
        await _autoDb.Create(auto);
        return new EntityResult(auto);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // return this error object if something broken
        return new EntityResult<Auto>("Error goes here");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is especially clean. Using some form of wrapper entity to contain the data about your success or failure, then a generic to actually accept useful data

Comment: @Evan that looks very clean and nice, i started doing something similar. Would you be able to put it together in context of the class i used as example, keen to know what it would actually look like (haven't used Generics much)

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thank you mate, that makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a return type to represent two different results e.g. success and failure. It will make the code hard to understand and, as time goes on, you will (probably) find that the return type will get abused and expanded to contain other (irrelevant?/unnecessary?) information.

Apply the `Single Responsibility Principle` to the return type:

- If the call was successful then return the correct object i.e. `Auto`
- If the call failed (i.e. you caught and exception) then create a custom exception to pass that failure back up the call stack. The name of your exception will make the code clearer than enclosing errors in a generic object.

Also your calling code will be much cleaner (and easier to maintain) if you use exception handling instead of an object with two purposes. Keep it simple.

Comment: While i agree with SRP, i need to be able to provide feedback to the client calling this service (which is part of a api). How would you return the expection back to the client to advise them that it failed and why? How do they know to change their input?

Comment: Are they using your API as a library call e.g. NuGet package? The caller can catch the exception themselves - you just need to document them :-) If it is a REST API then use HTTP Status Codes to indicate an error. Or is the client calling your code in a different way? (You've not added any of that detail in your question so it is hard to answer)

Comment: when i say client i mean frontend (in this case simple angular app). I use Rest API and HTTP status codes to indicate error. I've seen a lot of them usea custom response object to encompass the data so i been trying to learn and mimick that approach